# Cloudflare optimization techniques (free plan)

Tags: wordpress, caching, cdn, cloudflare

OK, so I'm trying to benefit from the CF's free plan and squeeze as much as I can out of it. The main goal is to get the site served from the CF cache so it will load faster in the browser, if only for the first visit and search engines. It is a Wordpress so it can be a little slower than other sites.
So, to have CF cache properly I have set the following rules. You probably know that under the free plan 3 is the maximum:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/*
Browser Cache TTL: a year, Cache Level: Cache Everything, Edge Cache TTL: a month
https://example.com/wp-admin/*
Security Level: High, Cache Level: Bypass, Disable Apps, Disable Performance
https://example.com/*
Auto Minify: HTML, CSS & JS, Browser Cache TTL: 30 minutes, Cache Level: No Query String, Edge Cache TTL: 2 hours, Email Obfuscation: On, Automatic HTTPS Rewrites: On
```

Exactly in this order. These should allow CF to cache the files stored in the wp-content (uploads etc) for the maximum amount of time, then ignore and bypass the wp-admin and finally serve all the others (products in my case, blog articles, pages and so on) from its cache, although these should have a shorter time. I've also set the caching level in the Cloudflare dashboard to '**No query string**'.

So far CF caches all the above and first time visitors or search engines should get a super fast page.

Next, I've added the following in the site's footer:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){var e="?"+(new Date).getTime();jQuery("a").each(function(){jQuery(this).attr("href",jQuery(this).attr("href")+e)})})</script>
```

This script appends the current date to all links on the page. By doing this I want the visitor to get the latest version of the page (ie from my server), not the one stored by CF, because CF should not cache ULRs such as https://example.com/samplepage?234523445345 as it was instructed previously, in both the cache settings and the page rules.

Now, what I'm worried about is CF caching pages belonging to logged in members, such as account details. While the string javascript does work and the members would click a link such as /account?23456456 and therefore the page should not get cached, I have to wonder 'what if?'.

So, is there any better way to achieve what I am trying to (fast loading without caching members pages and sensitive details, such as shopping cart)? Or is this the maximum I can get out of the free plan?

Answer (score 0):

In your case. Completely wordpress site? It is really very simple than other platforms to optimise. A new service called. Automatic Platform optimisation (APO). enable this in your cloudflare and install this in your wordpress plugin. Then connect the cloudflare to wordpress through APO.. And try to cache everything from your origin server. This will reduce the TTFB and RTT. This two will defenitely satisfy your site performance and speed.